# "to ride (in) a limousine"

Tags: prepositions

1. to ride in a limousine
2. to ride a limousine

I'm wondering if the above phrases make sense grammarly?

Comment: Please explain your doubts

Answer (score 2):

Both phrases make sense, but they imply somewhat different things.

Using the verb "ride" by itself (without "in") usually implies riding *on top of* something, whereas "ride in" implies riding *inside of* something, so "to ride a limousine" rather conjures up images of somebody riding on the roof of a limousine, not sitting inside it.

The exception to this rule is that in English (for some reason) we do tend to use just "ride" (without "in") for riding inside certain types of vehicles, such as "ride the bus" or "ride the train".  I think this is generally only true for mass-transit vehicles, though, and may also have something to do with whether it's possible to stand up while riding or not.

Comment: _Some_ varieties of English! As a British English speaker , I would never think of saying 'ride the bus/train' - I would say 'go/travel by bus/train'.

Comment: I agree with @KateBunting. I would not use _ride_ at all with a vehicle, other than a bike or motorcycle. _Ride in a train_ is nearly as unidiomatic to me as _Ride a train_.

Comment: Yes, at least in the UK you ride a horse or a bicycle, you don't ride a limousine.